# Introspector.getBeanInfo alternatives

Tags: java, javabeans, introspection

I'm writing an application with thousands of beans which I need to analyze at run time.
Currently I'm using Introspector.getBeanInfo which analyze the beans at run time and is very expensive (performance wise).
I was wondering if there are alternatives where I can the generate the bean info at build time and then access it on runtime.
The solution shouldn't rely on a specific IDE.